# Q.nfcall: TypeCast fails on an unspecified error

Tags: mysql, node.js, q

I'm learning node, and I'm having a hard time writing the back-end code for my database interactions. A promise based implementation looked a lot cleaner than doing it all using callbacks, so I did some digging and found Q.

I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong here, or even where. The error function inside `.then` seems to be catching the TypeCast error, but I don't know what I'd be doing that would be causing that error?

Running the following script

```
mysql = require('mysql');
var q = require('q')

var dbx = mysql.createConnection({
    //this is verified correct...
});

function getuser3(UserDisplayName) {
    return q.nfcall(dbx.query, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = ? ", [UserDisplayName])
    // This should wrap the query function with a promise, apply the arguments "SELECT..." ,
    // [UserDisplayName], and set up the last-argument-node-style callback so it fulfills the promise
    // with either a value or an error. If I understand correctly.
}

val = getuser3("Player2")
    .then(
            function (value) {
                console.log(value)
                return value //this should be sent to val in the outside scope, right?
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
    )
    .done()

console.log(val)
```

Returns the following error:

```
c:\Users\cb\Documents\guts\learning node\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:155
                throw e;
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined
    at query (c:\Users\cb\Documents\guts\learning node\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:185:34)
    at Promise.apply (c:\Users\cb\Documents\guts\learning node\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:1185:26)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (c:\Users\cb\Documents\guts\learning node\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
    at c:\Users\cb\Documents\guts\learning node\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:1411:14
    at runSingle (c:\Users\cb\Documents\guts\learning node\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (c:\Users\cb\Documents\guts\learning node\backend\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Process exited with code 1
```

I've tried several variations of the syntax, reading the docs as best I could, but I really don't know where to go next.